# Регулярные выражения в robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

Как я могу закрыть от индексации страницы, начинающие с цифр.

Например, есть:

```
www.domeins.ru/category/12354
www.domeins.ru/category/4548
www.domeins.ru/category/65
www.domeins.ru/category/4567897
```

Может, есть какой-то подобный вариант?

```
disallow /category/+d
```

Я себе представляю такой вариант, но, думаю, это неправильный:

```
disallow /category/0*
disallow /category/1*
disallow /category/2*
disallow /category/3*
disallow /category/4*
disallow /category/5*
disallow /category/6*
disallow /category/7*
disallow /category/8*
disallow /category/9*
```

Заранее спасибо!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Disallow: /0*
Disallow: /1*
Disallow: /2*
Disallow: /3*
Disallow: /4*
Disallow: /5*
Disallow: /6*
Disallow: /7*
Disallow: /8*
Disallow: /9*
```

Answer (score 3):

Спецификация robots.txt не допускает использования регулярных выражений. В url допустимы только * и &.

Подробнее смотрите в [официальном документе Google](http://robotstxt.org.ru/robotsexclusion/spec#_2).

Так что последний вариант в вашем вопросе как раз правильный.